# Cross compiled ncurses for UTF-8 displays incorrectly

Tags: python, vim, unicode, utf-8, ncurses

I have an embedded system, with a vt52u (unicode) terminal emulator, which displays UTF-8 characters correctly but I have cross compiled programs ( vim and python ) that do not display unicode characters properly on that terminal when using the ncursesw library.

I've done searches, but nothing available on the web seems to help...

Bash shell has these variables set:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mnt/sd/lib  # all libraries, cross compiled, are located here
TERM=vt52u
TERMCAP='vt52u|vt52 with UTF-8:am:eo:rs=\Ee\Eb0\Eco:is=\EE\Ee:nl=^j:sr=\Ei:bl=^g:ta=^i:ho=\EH:cr=^m:le=\ED:nd=\EC:do=\EB:up=\EA:ta=^i:nw=^m:xn:cm=\EY%+ %+ :it#8:co#75:li#24:sc=\Ej:rc=\Ek:vi=\Ef:ve=\Ee:so=\Eb0\Ec4:se=\Eb0\Eco:mh=\Eb8\Eco:mr=\Ebo\Ec0:me=\Eb0\Eco:cl=\EH\EJ:cd=\EJ:ce=\EK:km:ku=^p:kd=^n:kr=^f:kl=^b:kb=^h:'
LOCALE=
```

And I know the unicode terminal is fine, because I can run the following program to get it to display UTF-8 characters perfectly.

```
#!/bin/env python
#coding=UTF-8

charset = [
0x2205, 0x2629, 0x00B2, 0x2663, 0x2666, 0x00B1, 0x221A, 0x266B,
0x2190, 0x2524, 0x2500, 0x2534, 0x253C, 0x251C, 0x2193, 0x2191,
0x00B0, 0x2665, 0x00AE, 0x2660, 0x00B7, 0x00A4, 0x00A4, 0x00A4,
0x00D7, 0x00B5, 0x2126, 0x252C, 0x250C, 0x2510, 0x2514, 0x2518
]

for i in charset:
    print unichr( i ).encode("UTF-8"),
    if i == 0x2191: print
print


bash-4.3#./testunicode
bash-4.3# ∅ ☩ ² ♣ ♦ ± √ ♫ ← ┤ ─ ┴ ┼ ├ ↓ ↑
bash-4.3# ° ♥ ® ♠ · ¤ ¤ ¤ × µ Ω ┬ ┌ ┐ └ ┘
```

But when I try to get the box drawing characters to display using curses (ncursesw) in a python program, or edit a UTF-8 text file using vim (which is linked to ncursesw);  I end up with the screen printing an invalid unicode box, followed by extra symbols like ~T~B, ~T~L, and many other variations for each unicode character. So, for some reason ncursesw is outputting invalid UTF-8 characters....

I know it's linked right, and there is no conflicting ncurses library; only ncursesw exists.

I configured the ncurses-5.9 library for compilation like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/mnt/sd --without-cxx --without-cxx-binding --without-ada --without-manpages --without-progs --without-tests --without-curses-h --with-build-cc=gcc --with-shared --without-normal --without-debug --without-profile --without-gpm --without-dlsym --without-sysmouse --build=i686-linux --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --without-pthread --enable-widec --with-fallbacks=vt52 --with-terminfo-dirs=/etc/terminfo --disable-big-core --enable-termcap --with-termpath=/Data/termcap
```

As an example: The following program runs fine on my desktop linux ~VT102 -- but malfunctions on the embedded system when run on the vt52u:

```
#!/bin/env python
# coding=UTF-8
board=[
"","",
u"   ┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐",
u"   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │",
u"   │   │ ├───→───→───→ │   │   │   │   │   │ ├───→───→───→ │   │   │" ]

board = ( i.encode("utf-8") for i in board )

import curses
import locale
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL,"" )

screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho() # no echoing
curses.cbreak() # no keyboard buffering

# Setup the playing board screen. 
for i,s in enumerate( board ): screen.addstr( i,0,s )
screen.refresh()

import time
time.sleep(2)

# Return everything to normal
curses.echo()
curses.nocbreak()
curses.endwin()
```

EDIT:  I Discovered one possible reason for the bug -- glibc, being cross compiled, did not have the proper path to the /mnt/sd/share/i18n/charmap  or /mnt/sd/share/i18n/locales directories.  It had only partial paths which Make or configure prefixed by an erroneous '/', not the target system's actual root path /mnt/sd.   When no file is found, glibc apparently defaults back to the "C" or "POSIX" locale and ignores the environment variable.

I'm not sure if I have to re-compile glibc and manually edit the makefile, or if there is a way to manually set the path after the system is built.... ?? any ideas.
???

Comment: Have you tried porting the example to Python 3? There's a small chance things will work differently with 3's text model. The [Python Mailing List](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-list) also has a few overly competent people in this area, so you can try asking there.

Comment: No, although I might try that later next week.  I know the error is with the NCURSES, because it doesn't matter whether I use Python or a "C" program; they all fail identically.  You can simulate the failure on a working Linux xterm or console terminal by setting the locale variable in the above python test program to "C".  That produces the "~T~L" symbols that I see on the embedded system, and garbles the display in nearly the same way; so I tend to think the problem is with the locale variables... or the standard C library.

Comment: Wait, "VT52U"? This is a thing?!

Comment: :)  YES ! it is.  Do you want the source code? It draws an ascii font on the linux framebuffer and simulates a DEC VT52, but has unicode UTF-8 decoding capability.   It's main purpose is to be a console on e-paper devices like the sony PRS-900 (E-Brook) under arm processor.

Comment: typo: that's innsbrook, as in the broadsheet linux kernel driver for e-ink epaper displays. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ncurses relies on the standard C library which requires a compiled in path to the directories with the internationalized files in them, or else NCURSES will automatically default back to the POSIX locale (AKA "C" locale) and won't do UTF-8.

Cross compiling on a build system where the locales are stored in a different location than the host can cause the autoconfig script to misidentify the directory and then the embedded system will not be able to do UTF-8 even if the locale variables are set correctly ... and worse, it's possible for no error messages to be generated by the failure.

But: If the path is wrong, then you won't be able to see any locales except POSIX & C when running:

```
locale -a
```

Setting up a dummy directory on the build system with the internationalized files, and then recompiling the standard C library is one way to solve the problem; but it may require root priveleges.

Alternately, there is an environment variable "I18NPATH" that can be set when using the gnu standard C library (glibc); it is supposed to override the compiled in path.  If the install prefix on the embedded system was "/mnt/sd", then from bash shell -- just do:

```
export I18NPATH="/mnt/sd/share/i18n"
```

In either event, once the corrected path is available/installed -- the system should operate normally.  If not, check to make sure the locale has actually been generated for the combination of country charmap and UTF-8, which is desired (using "locale -a" to list them all).

If it doesn't exist, it can be created very simply using the "localedef" utility. eg: To create a USA english locale with UTF-8 support, just do:

```
localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
```

then, be sure the locale varaibles are set and exported:

```
export LOCALE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

And then running locale with no arguments should show all variables as being en_US.UTF-8 ... and everything will work fine from then on.